# how to find what functions need to be defined for a protocol interface

Tags: clojure

If i want my type to implement a function, eg. `contains?` how do I find out which interface to extend?

Similarily, if I see an interface, eg. `clojure.lang.ILookup` how do I find out which methods are required to be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what methods an interface requires (including inheritied members) use java reflection at the repl:

```
 (clojure.pprint/pprint (.getMethods clojure.lang.ILookup))
 [#<Method public abstract java.lang.Object clojure.lang.ILookup.valAt(java.lang.Object)>,
  #<Method public abstract java.lang.Object clojure.lang.ILookup.valAt(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)>]
```

If you're on Clojure 1.2, you could also use `clojure.contrib.repl-utils/show`

Answer (score 0):

First, clone the source from here:  (git) https://github.com/clojure/clojure.git (browser) https://github.com/clojure/clojure

Look at the source for contains? in src/clj/clojure/core.clj, it turns around and calls clojure.lang.RT.contains.

That file is in src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java, you can see that it will work with instances of Associate, IPersistentSet, Map, Set, and it also looks like it will index into arrays and strings, so pick what makes sense for your situation.

Likewise, the source for ILookup is in that same directory. You can find out about how interfaces work in Java if you're not familiar with them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Back to contains? though, you might be able to use a record to achieve what you want.

e.g.

```
main=> (defrecord Action [time key args state])
main.Action
main=> (def action (Action. (System/currentTimeMillis) "key" ["arg1" "arg2"] nil))
#'warscor.main/action
warscor.main=> (contains? action :time)
true
warscor.main=> (contains? action :state)
true
warscor.main=> (contains? action :foo)  
false
warscor.main=> (def action (assoc action :foo "bar"))
#'warscor.main/action
warscor.main=> (contains? action :foo)               
true
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can answer any question on stackoverflow by telling the guy to "go look at the source code" :) I need a way to do it in the repl.

Comment: If you're familiar with the reflection API's then you could do it some of it that way (inspecting the interface). Can't get at Java source in REPL. Which you frequently need to do if you want to understand what's going on. It also wasn't clear from your question that you have a Java background (there are a lot of Clojure folk with little to none). I felt it was easier to explain this way. Good luck.